# Define div id inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Using a for loop in javascript to create multiple html div's.

```
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
     document.getElementById("rotate").innerHTML+="<div><div><a href='' id='idWithIndex_i'>";
     document.getElementById("idWithIndex_i").innerHTML+=lines[i];
     document.getElementById("rotate").innerHTML+="</a></div></div>";
}
```

The html should look like this for index 0:

```
<div>
     <div>
          <a href='' id='idWithIndex_0'>
               line1
          </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to define the index in the id of the anchor. How can I change the javascript? Thanks.

Comment: try to install jquery string concatenation plugin

Comment: @degr is concatenating strings (i.e. `id='idWithIndex_" + i + "'"`) so out of fashion that we need a plugin to do that?

Comment: @degr did something go way over my head and you were just being sarcastic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your `i` is just a part of a string, here's what you want:

```
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
     document.getElementById("rotate").innerHTML+="<div><div><a href='' id='idWithIndex_" + i + ">";
     document.getElementById("idWithIndex_" + i).innerHTML+=lines[i];
     document.getElementById("rotate").innerHTML+="</a></div></div>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I misspelled length in the question sorry. I was missing the second plus sign that was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in this line:

```
for(var i = 0; i < lines.lenght; i++){
```

`lenght` does not exists in javascript. Use `length` instead.

Also, for concatenation, use this:

```
document.getElementById("rotate").innerHTML+='<div><div><a href="" id="idWithIndex_'+i+'">';
```

or using `string` **templates** from `ES6` in order to obtain a **cleaner** solution.

```
document.getElementById("rotate").innerHTML+=`<div><div><a href="" id="idWithIndex_${i}">`;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
id='idWithIndex_"+i+"'
```

You need to break out of the string and then concatenate with `+` the variable.

In steps:

1. "idWithIndex_" is the first part of your fixed string
2. with `+` you append something to the former part
3. we append the variable `i`
4. after the variable we append the rest of the fixed string using another `+`.

Also type in your for loop: `length` instead of `lenght`

There is a way nicer way to do this:

```js
 var counter = 0;
 
 //method 1 - createElement
 document.querySelector("#add_method1").addEventListener("click", function(){
 //add a click event to the add button
 
 var node = document.createElement("div"); //create a new element
 var innernode = document.createElement("div"); //create second node
 var linknode = document.createElement("a");
 
 linknode.setAttribute("href", '');
 linknode.setAttribute("id", "idWithIndex_" + counter) //set id
 linknode.innerHTML += "test"+counter; //lines[i] in your code;
 counter++;
 
 //time to append
 innernode.appendChild(linknode);
 node.appendChild(innernode);
 document.getElementById("rotate").appendChild(node);
 },true);
 
  //method 2 - cloneNode
 document.querySelector("#add_method2").addEventListener("click", function(){
 //add a click event to the add button
 var cloned = document.querySelector(".copynode").cloneNode(true); //true for deep cloning
 cloned.removeAttribute("class"); //remove class
 var a = cloned.querySelector("div > a"); //select link
 a.setAttribute("id", "idWithIndex_" + counter) //set id
 a.innerHTML += "test"+counter; //lines[i] in your code;
 counter++;
 
 //time to append
 document.getElementById("rotate").appendChild(cloned);
 },true);
```

```css
/*css for method 2 */
.hidden {
  display: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="rotate"></div>
<button id="add_method1">add using document.createElement</button>
<button id="add_method2">add using element.cloneNode</button>


<!-- html for method 2 -->
<div class="copynode hidden">
  <div>
    <a href=""></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know the feeling when you write long answer and nobody votes you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
     document.getElementById("rotate").innerHTML+="<div><div><a href='' id='idWithIndex_"+i+"'>";
     document.getElementById("idWithIndex_"+i).innerHTML+=lines[i];
     document.getElementById("rotate").innerHTML+="</a></div></div>";
}
```

First off, you have a type at `.lenght`.

Also, The `"i"` is not a part of the string, its a variable, so you need to add the value of `i` as the id od the div, not the string `"i"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(var i = 0; i < lines.lenght; i++){
 document.getElementById("rotate").innerHTML+="<div><div><a href='' id='idWithIndex_"+i+"'>";var id = "idWithIndex_"+i;
 document.getElementById(id).innerHTML+=lines[i];
 document.getElementById("rotate").innerHTML+="</a></div></div>";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```js
var lines = [1,2,3,4]
var i;
for(i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
     document.getElementById("rotate").innerHTML+="<div><div><a href='' id='idWithIndex_"+i+"'> " + lines[i]+"</a></div></div>";
}
```

```html
<div id="rotate">Hi</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you need to either concatenate the values into the string or use a template string to inject them into the string.

I wanted to suggest a little refactoring. DOM access is relatively expensive, with 3 `getElementById` queries and 3 changes to the DOM via `innerHTML` per loop, that creates a lot of unnecessary overhead. In most cases it probably doesn't matter, but if there were a lot of items in `lines`, it could bring the browser to its knees. It would be better to build a string of the HTML you are injecting and just inject once:

```js
let lines = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let linesHtml = ''; // buffer for the HTML we are building

for(let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  // there is no need to create the link and then inject content into it,
  // we can just inject the content right into the element in the HTML
  linesHtml += `<div>
    <div>
      <a href='' id='idWithIndex_${i}'>
        ${lines[i]}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>`;
}
// now that we know what we are injecting, make a single DOM update
document.getElementById("rotate").innerHTML += linesHtml;
```

```css
div {
 border: 1px solid #000;
 padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rotate"></div>
```

I used a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of a normal string because it allows you to easily create multi-line strings, for easily readable embedded HTML. This can help a lot with the maintainability of your code. Any recent browser [supports](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-template_literals) them (IE isn't recent; if you have to support it, you have my condolences).